# Angular directive error : Unable to load template from templateUrl - fails when I load template via 'templateUrl' (continuous loading in browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm not sure why it shows below warnings in console and infinitely loads page, I'm just calling a template which is actually calling another directly in which I'm calling another html with templateUrl. Below is my code. Thanks in advance.

route file, which will load `step-1.tpl.html` on `get-started/1`

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/get-started/1', {
        templateUrl: 'get-started/step-1.tpl.html',
    });
}])
```

`step-1.tpl.html` - file in which I'm using my directive when above url is loaded

```
<div ng-controller="addWebsite">
      <div step1></div>
</div>
```

my directive code

```
angular.module('add-website', [])

.controller('addWebsite', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
        name: 'Naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };
}])

.directive('step1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: 'add-website/step1.html'
    };
});
```

add-website/step1.html

```
<div>Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}</div>
```

I'm getting this error when I hit `/get-started/1`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please include angular-route.js and inject 'ngRoute' in module dependency

Comment: Still no change, any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

In your .config file, what does your angular.module() declaration look like? At a guess I'd say you're doing something like you have for your controllers, like this:

```
angular.module('add-website', [])
```

Only have one like this, the one on your controller for example should look like this:

```
angular.module('add-website')
```

But Nishant is also right, you need to inject ngRoute too.

Comment: `angular.module('get-started', [])` it looks like this in .config file. What should I do, there is no change even though I converted into angular.module('get-started', ['ngRoute'])

Comment: On the .config file, make it like you wrote. For the controller write angular.module('get-started').controller.....

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a path issue! :( `get-started/step-1.tpl.html` should be `shared/get-started/step-1.tpl.html`. Thanks!